# Is it possible to build an iphone app that lists available wifis and allows the user to connect one?

Tags: iphone, ios4, wifi

My question is as the title states. Is it possible or is that restricted to the settings app?
I have tried searching for an answer in the docs but no luck.

Comment: There is an app for that! (Already) eWifi: http://www.appstorehq.com/ewifi-iphone-121746/app )
So it means that is possible.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Apple's "no private APIs" policy includes what you'd need to do this. I'm pretty sure their specific example of what not to do was a wifi sniffer.

[The news back when they did this](http://www.cultofmac.com/apple-is-purging-the-app-store-of-wi-fi-stumblers/32289)